# Azure functions not showing under "Add new item" in visual studio 2022

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm learning Azure functions, and after setting up an initial project the tutorial suggests to select Project > Add new Item > Azure function.

On my end, I don't see Add New Item in the menu, but if I right click on the `.csproj` file I see add new item, however, I don't see an option for adding an azure function.

Expected behavior (screenshot from tutorial)
[image]

Actual behavior on my end:
[image]

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904799/cant-find-azure-functions-when-setting-up-new-project-in-vs-2017#:%7E:text=Right-click%20on%20the%20project%20and%20choose%20Add%20-%3E,Azure%20Function%20C%23%20code%20file%20created%20for%20you.) where it says to add "Azure Functions and web job tools" though I don't see that as an option on my side.
[image]

Also referenced this post:
[Missing Azure functions template under Add new item in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70048148/missing-azure-functions-template-under-add-new-item-in-visual-studio)

It recommended making sure I have the Azure SDK workload (which I do) and installing this SDK: Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions

I went to my folder and ran this command so as far as I know it's installed at this point.
*dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions --version 4.1.3*

This is my current file structure and .csproj file.

[image]

When setting up VS, I selected Azure SDK as a workload.  Also, if I go to File > New > Project, I have an option for Azure functions.

Any insight as to why it's not showing up for me would be appreciated.   If you need me to clarify anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As you have followed one of my practical workarounds #[7004818](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70050648/16630138), make sure you have done the below configuration:

1. Download & Install the Azure Functions Core Tools, VS 2022 Current Version 17.4.4
2. In Visual Studio installer, Select the below options:
   - Web & Cloud: ASP .NET & Web development, Azure Development
   - Desktop & Mobile: .NET Desktop development
   - Other toolsets: Visual Studio Extension Development
3. You are developing the Azure Functions in .NET So, install the respective Version SDK & Runtime.
4. On the Same above Post, the user @*GraceA* added a point to my answer which is to check the [NuGet Package](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json) Source Install/Update is missing and there are steps given in the answer for updating/installing it.

[VS NuGet Package Update Gif Image1]
[VS Azure Functions Toolset Update Gif Image 2]

[image]

5. The Same issue registered on MS Q&A Forum #[386611](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/386611/creating-azure-function-with-visual-studio-doesnt) where the user has resolved it by updating the NuGet Package Source.

[image]